# Modify the location of php-fpm.conf and php-fpm.d/*.conf?

Tags: php

Is it possible to use a specific file as php-fpm.conf, that is NOT located in the /etc?

I am thinking something like NGINX. I can modify the loation of the default config file of NGINX, but I havent find a way to do the same with php-fpm.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly, all you have to do is pass the `--fpm-config` option when starting up FPM

```
/usr/local/sbin/php-fpm --fpm-config <file>
```

You can also specify a specific php.ini path by

```
/usr/local/sbin/php-fpm -c <path>
```

I have mine located in /usr/local/etc/ where I also keep my PEAR and other PHP configurations.